# Connect iOS App to Bluetooth device not BLE

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I want to connect bluetooth device to my iOS app. That device perfectly works in android as it first paired via bluetooth (from outside the app) and send/recive command from inside the app. But that device is not getting in my list when I am turning on it in iPhone setting.

After a research I come to know that Corebluetooth can connect only with BLE. Now How many possible way to connect my app with that device. Please help me with this.

> Is there any app on App Store from where I can scan that device ? It
>   wii be also helpful for me.
>
> I also come to know about apple MFI program, but how will work ? Is it
>   paid ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can only connect to non-BLE peripherals if they are MFi certified and your app is on the permitted list for that peripheral.  You cannot connect to generic Bluetooth peripherals using legacy profiles such as SPP

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes I found it, but how it will work,Is it paid ? I need to submit my device detail to MFI program ? Please let me know.

Comment: You can get started here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/ There is an [FAQ](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action) on the program.  On the whole, it is much simpler to use BLE if you can.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have read and asked question too in MFI. Using BLE will be the last choice. do you know any app that scans bluetooth device ?

Comment: It is not possible to create an app that scans legacy bluetooth devices.  LightBlue is a very good app for scanning BLE devices.